# Rails accessing and manipulate user_ip_address

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, ruby-on-rails-3.1, request

I want to check number of times a device ip address come to my site `(root to=>home#index)`,if the address came to my site more than once then excute a piece of code(anything).How do i accomplish that with rails?In other words How do i access and set a variable to store number of  user ip_address login in `index action`?Root page is home#index.To clarify more a user dont have to be a registered user,I just want to track by computer ip address.I need help with commented out words in index action.There is devise `current_sign_in_ip` but i am not sure if that was meant to solve this problem scenario because i am very new to devise and rails in general.Thank you so much!

controller

```
       class HomeController < ApplicationController

       def index
       #access user ip address
       #set a variable to increment number of times the address come to a site
       # if no_of_ip_login is_greater_than_1 #In other words if it is a returning user

       redirect_to :controller=>"home" ,:action=>"show"
       end

       end
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use

```
ip_addr = request.env['REMOTE_ADDR']
```

also:

```
request.remote_ip
```

Just want to mention also that if you are behind a load balancer, the
REMOTE_ADDR may return the load balancer's IP, not the actual client's. 
In this case, you can typically use something like:

```
ip_addr = request.env['X_FORWARDED_FOR']
```

So I recommended request.remote_ip. It returns HTTP_CLIENT_IP or 
X_FORWARDED_FOR if present, otherwise REMOTE_IP.

Comment: Thank you for the answer but how do i know if i am behind load balancer?sorry I am very new in rails

Comment: Load balancing is a computer networking methodology to distribute workload across multiple computers or a computer cluster.If your server has load balancer then ip_addr = request.env['REMOTE_ADDR'] will return you the load balancer's IP.Its only at this case. But request.remote_ip will always  return you the users IP.

Comment: Then i think `request.remote_ip` is the better choice.I am going to deploy on heroku if that info would help.what is advantage or disadvantage of using one over the other?

Comment: Yes request.remote_ip is the better choice :-)

Comment: Very helpful. I was accidentally collecting load balancer addresses.